# Tansform.position assign attempt for 'Enemy(Clone)' is not valid. Input position is {NaN, NaN, NaN}

Tags: unity-game-engine

From my research I can see I am getting a vector issue (it looks like I divide by 0 but I don't do an divisions in my script).

I checked every script I have for positions and tried to catch it between trace statements. Couldnt do it. It looks like its in some update or fixed update but I have no clue where.

This error comes up SOMETIMES right as an enemy is killed.

I feel it has something to do with its position. Clicking on this error does nothing, but SOMETIMES it highlights the gameobject that got the bad transform passed to it.

Is there somewhere in your code I could get getting a NAN vector that I can look for?

Right as an enemy dies I will get a lot of these, and once its dead (destroyed) this problem goes away. It will play through a bit of animation, triggering the error each frame, and then when the enemy dies the error stops.

Clicking the error will only highlight the gameobject but will not open to a script where this occurs.

It comes up maybe 1 in 5 times whenever an enemy is killed...

Here is the enemy dying script (it doesn't set positions so the problem likely does not lie here)

```
public void killSelf()
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isAttacking",false);
        _animator.SetBool("isDead",true);
        StartCoroutine(processKillSelf());
    }

    IEnumerator processKillSelf()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);//its a 30 frame animation
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Is there a way to FORCE unity3D to break on this error and let me look up the stack trace?

Not having the stack trace is the only reason I can't find where this is occurring.

Comment: What does the script for the enemy dying look like?

Comment: It's pretty simple and no positions are set. Do you know a way I can force Unity3D to give the me the stack trace so I can at least get the scrip this occurs on?

Comment: You should be able to see the file and line number where it goes wrong in your error message in Unity. (example here : http://bit.ly/1skN43X). Is that not the case for you?

Comment: No it doesnt sadly. It says exactly: Tansform.position assign attempt for 'Enemy(Clone)' is not valid. Input position is {NaN, NaN, NaN} and clicking on it does nothing

Comment: Here is link to image: http://postimg.org/image/csir0gnrz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

It was not the character, but an HP bar on the character. The local scale of that HP bar was having one of the values set to 0 on death. Making sure the value is at least 0.1f fixed this problem:

```
float x = _hpBarMaxScale * health/healthmax>0?(_hpBarMaxScale * health/healthmax):0.1f;
hpBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x,hpBar.transform.localScale.y,hpBar.transform.localScale.z);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I just had a similar problem and maybe it helps someone in the future.

As you already noticed this always happens if somwhere you try to devide a value by `0`.

In my case I just couldn't find where I possibly divided by `0` that easy and unfortunately something like

```c#
try
{
    transform.position = possiblyBrokenVector3;
}
catch
{
}
```

didn't catch it either so I couldn't set up proper brakepoints since it was called in `Update`.

---

What you always can do is actually checking the values for `NaN`. I directly made it an extension method for checking Vector3:

```c#
public static Vector3Extensions
{
    public static bool ContainsNaN(this Vector3 vector)
    {
        return float.IsNaN(vector.x) || float.IsNaN(vector.y) || float.IsNaN(vector.z);
    }
}
```

Now I can always check before I assign like

```c#
if(possiblyBrokenVector3.ContainsNaN)
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Ignoring a NaN vector here!", this);
}
else
{
    transform.position = possiblyBrokenVector3;
}
```

set a Brakepoint on the Debug line and finally step through the call history to see how the broken input value actually was produced.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code I can't say for sure but it sounds like reference is not being updated internally (ie. something is pointing to a vector that has already been destroyed.) I would poke around your animation code to see if that turns up anything.

For what its worth `Object.Destroy` has an optional second argument that is a delay timer. ( http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html ) so you could re-write your code like this:

```
public void killSelf() 
{
    _animator.SetBool("isAttacking",false);
    _animator.SetBool("isDead",true);
    Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
}
```

and totally omit the `processKillSelf()` coroutine.